# Missing page controls when calling SelectedIndexChanged of DropDownList (asp.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Here is my problem :

I have an asp:Panel in which I dynamically create a list of .ascx controls.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel">
           </asp:Panel>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The controls are correctly created. I also have a button calling an "onserverclick" event :

```
<button runat="server" id="myButton" onserverclick="myButton_Click" type="button" class="button"> My Button </button>
```

And finally, I created an asp:DropDownList like this one, with a server event triggered on SelectedIndexChanged :

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myDdl" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDdl_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="myDdl_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In response to the two events (myButton_Click and myDdl_SelectedIndexChanged), I'm trying to parse the child controls of *myPanel*, like this :

```
ControlCollection controls = myPanel.Controls;
```

This is the very first line of code within the two response methods. 
When clicking on *myButton*, all the controls of *myPanel* are correctly retrieved.

**BUT**

When calling the SelectedIndexChanged event of *myDdl*, the only child control retrieved in the ControlCollection is the first one, although I can clearly see them on the webpage.

I would appreciate some help, I'm stuck on this since yesterday :(

Thank you !

**EDIT**

Here is how I'm creating my controls during the page creation:

```
while(condition)
{    
    MyControl newControl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl.ascx");
    // Setting MyControl attributes
    ....
    myPanel.Controls.Add(newControl);
}
```

Comment: Edited ! Thank you

Comment: If you create controls dynamically, you will have to recreate them on every page load, and that includes a PostBack.

Comment: Yep, was about to comment what @VDWWD said. Not recreating dynamic controls on every postback is the most common cause of them being missing

Comment: Agree, but is the button_onClick event not firing a PostBack too ? In this case I should not be able to retrieve my controls at all. The two events are firing a call to the Page_Load method.

-> "When clicking on myButton, all the controls of myPanel are correctly retrieved."

Comment: @ClémentS., true, but again, we do not see your code here. Are you doing exactly same things in both event handlers? Could it be that "condition" holds when you click the button but not when you select something in the ddl?

Comment: @Andrei The "while(condition)", which creates my controls, is called at the very first loading of the page (!Page.IsPostBack), and is not called on PostBack. I manually re-create my controls when I need to ; and yes, I am doing the exact same thing in the two event handlers and there is no code other than the page_load triggering before the handlers. :( I'm thinking this possibly has to do with the page life cycle, but I can't be sure.